# React JS lodash get in the same function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, material-ui

I want to to display the two object of string in same line using Lodash get ? or it is possible to use chain (_.chain(vehicle).get('test').get('test2)).

This is the sample JSON File

```
     {
      "results": [
        {
          "vehicle": {
            "plate_no": "ABC 1234",
            "model": "Toyota Innova"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I'm using Material-ui Card and my code looks like this.

```
  {_.map(this.state.vehicle, (d, idx) =>{
    return(
    <Col xs={6} style={{margin: '20px 0 5px' }}>
      <Card key={d.id}>
        <CardHeader
          avatar="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/"
          title={_.get(d.vehicle, 'model') - _.get(d.vehicle, 'plate_no')}
          actAsExpander={true}
          showExpandableButton={true}
          style={{backgroundColor: Colors.grey200}}
        />
```

and my goal is to display the title looks like this.

Toyota Innova - ABC 1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#at) with an array of the properties you want, by the order you want them, and then Array#join them:

```js
const d = {
  "vehicle": {
    "plate_no": "ABC 1234",
    "model": "Toyota Innova"
  }
};

const result = _.at(d.vehicle, ['model', 'plate_no']).join(' - ');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of using lodash, you can use simple destructuring (code not tested):

```
  {_.map(this.state.vehicle, ({ vehicle: { model, plate_no } }, idx) =>{ // destructure the vehicle object
    return(
    <Col xs={6} style={{margin: '20px 0 5px' }}>
      <Card key={d.id}>
        <CardHeader
          avatar="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/"
          title={`${model} - ${plate_no}`} // use the destructured props
          actAsExpander={true}
          showExpandableButton={true}
          style={{backgroundColor: Colors.grey200}}
        />
```

Comment: Thank man :) It works but somehow ? you can't use two lodash function ?

Comment: You can always use 2 lodash functions - `_.get()` like you did in a template string `${_.get(d.vehicle, 'model')} - ${_.get(d.vehicle, 'plate_no')}`.

Comment: Thanks for The help :)